# Lyapunov Theory to Prove that a Controller minimize the Control Energy or Actuation

Tags: control, control-system

Hello Control Engineers!

I am currently trying  to prove that certain controller actually tried to minimize the control actuation or energy, like utilizes less battery as compared to the classical control techniques. The one way i have thought is to prove it experimentally by implementing both controllers on a hardware and show the plots etc. But, I am interested in proving it mathematically as well.  Now, since the controller is nonlinear, Lyapunov is the choice i have heard, but i am not very familiar with it. I just want a certain direction from the experts, what are the tools that i can use to prove it and how can i prove it? Any related papers, books etc?

Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: I've used Lyapunov many times to prove control system stability, but never have I seen it used for optimality. Can you direct me to some sources that apply Lyapunov to optimality proofs? I'd be very interested.

Comment: @Bryan When energy is taken as conservative (given the system under consideration) then I don't see it applying. From this [Wiki page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/617979/lyapunov-theory-to-prove-that-a-controller-minimize-the-control-energy-or-actuat) I find the following quote as suggestive, *"Lyapunov stability theory has no application to conservative systems..."*

Comment: so what tools can be used foe this purpose?

Comment: @AdeelAhsan Perhaps if you share more of the system and the control law we could give some guidance. Another avenue would be to approach the math stackexchange for some help:
https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: its a quadcopter, I am trying to prove that certain controllers consume less rpms (speed of motors) as compared to the traditional PID control etc